# The command "git status" results in "Segmentation fault"

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I am working on windows, and I am using bash to work with Git.

I have cloned a remote repo, and built it, which produced some object files and HEX/elf files.

I don't want to lose these object files, so I created a branch from my local repository, and I was planning to commit these object files into this new branch.

So I created the branch "SW_version_x" using the command:
**git branch SW_version_x**

Then I switched to the branch:
**git checkout SW_version_x**

Then I tried to check the untracked files using the command:
**git status**

But it produced to me "Segmentation fault". 
Are there any log/ error files which I should check, to know the reason for this failure?

Comment: You'll have to run it under a debugger.

Comment: Stop your antivirus and try. You must be behind the firewall. If doesn’t work change bash opening path. It will go away if you use the "c:\program files\git\git-bash.exe" instead of "c:\program files\git\bin\bash

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really a question but rather a bug report; The Git-for-Windows project has [its bug tracker](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/).

Comment: …in addition to my suggestion to use the bug tracker, let me tell up front that 1) it's best to first search the tracker for similar issues—[this](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+%22segmentation+fault%22) would be a good start; 2) when filing a bug, be sure to specify exact versions of the platform and the GfW installation bundle; 3) ideally be prepared to hand off the offending repository to a GfW maintainer to reproduce the bug.

Comment: If you have troubles understanding how bug tracker works (say, not sure how to verify whether your installed version is affected), feel free to post a request to [the project's mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/git-for-windows); please be as detailed as possible.